# call a variable from main method in another - java

Tags: java, variables, exception, call, throws

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.example.com/example.php");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
    String inputLine;
    inputLine = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(inputLine);

   in.close();
}
```

I dont know too much Java and I am just trying to use the first line from a url as a string for a project.

so how can i use the variable "input line" in the same class but in another method that looks like this:

```
public void run(){//content}
```

i would appreciate any helpful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `run()` method has to be static.

Second, just pass a parameter to it: `public static void run(String inputLine)`

An alternative would be to make a static instance field called `inputLine`, and then just use it across methods without needing a parameter on the `run` method.

As a beginner, this must be mind-boggling. You may want to follow some "Java for Beginners" tutorials. These are really basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable as Object level instead of method level:

```
class Test {

String inputLine;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.example.com/example.php");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    Test t = new Test();
    t.inputLine = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(inputLine);

   in.close();
}

public void run() {
 //inputLine will be available here
}

}
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private variable, asign in.readLine to it and then use that in the run() method:

```
private String inputLine;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.example.com/example.php");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
    inputLine = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(inputLine);

    in.close();
}

public void run(){
    //whatever you want to do with inputLine
}
```